# React Native component not re-rendering on state change

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I'm having trouble re-rendering a component after it receives new props that change its state. I'm very new to both React Native and using hooks so please bear with me. Here is the component in question:

```
function AreaChart(timeScale) {

  const width = Dimensions.get('window').width;
  const height = Dimensions.get('window').height;
  const [areaChartJS, setAreaChartJS] = useState(chartJS.areaChart(width, timeScale.timeScale));

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(timeScale.timeScale);
    setAreaChartJS(chartJS.areaChart(width, timeScale.timeScale));
  }, [areaChartJS, timeScale]);

  return(
    <View>
      <WebView
        originWhitelist={['*']}
        useWebKit={true}
        source={{ html: areaChartHtml }}
        domStorageEnabled={true}
        javaScriptEnabled={true}
        style={styles.WebViewStyle}
        injectedJavaScript={areaChartJS}
      />
      <Text>{timeScale.timeScale}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

This requires some explanation. I'm using a charting library designed only for the web, so I have to use a WebView here in order to render it. areaChartHtml and areaChartJS are HTML and JS code that gets injected into the WebView since it's all local. These are both strings that the WebView parses and renders. I have the JS code in another file called chartJS which I call while passing the width of the device and the timeScale so that the chart is rendered dynamically based on these variables.

The issue is, after changing the timeScale, the component doesn't get re-rendered and keeps using the initial timeScale passed from the parent component during the initial render. In the useEffect hook, I'm logging the timeScale and I'm getting the right values, but even though I'm changing the state with the setAreaChartJS function using the new timeScale prop, a re-render doesn't get triggered. The `<Text>` element under the WebView also shows the correct real-time value of timeScale, and even logging it from the external chartJS file shows the correct value, but the new JS code isn't being injected into the WebView. The fact that the `<Text>` gets updated with the new values tells me that the component *is* getting re-rendered but the WebView isn't pulling the new areaChartJS from the state.

When the component completely unmounts and mounts again, the timeScale gets registered correctly and the chart gets rendered accordingly. How do I achieve this without a complete re-mounting of the component?

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to get the desired behavior by putting a `ref` on the WebView and calling its `.reload()` method in `useEffect`. I don't know the inner workings of WebView but I assume it saves the initial value of the injected JS somewhere and won't inject new values even if a re-render of the component is happening, unless you force a reload this way. This is how the component looks now:

```
function AreaChart(timeScale) {

  const width = Dimensions.get('window').width;
  const height = Dimensions.get('window').height;
  const [areaChartJS, setAreaChartJS] = useState(chartJS.areaChart(width, timeScale.timeScale));
  const [currTimeScale, setCurrTimeScale] = useState('1h');

  useEffect(() => {
    setAreaChartJS(chartJS.areaChart(width, timeScale.timeScale));
    if (currTimeScale !== timeScale.timeScale) {
      WebViewRef.reload();
      setCurrTimeScale(timeScale.timeScale);
    }
  }, [timeScale]);

  return(
    <View style={{flex: 1, height: 300}}>
      <WebView
        ref={WVref => (WebViewRef = WVref)}
        originWhitelist={['*']}
        useWebKit={true}
        source={{ html: areaChartHtml }}
        domStorageEnabled={true}
        javaScriptEnabled={true}
        style={styles.WebViewStyle}
        injectedJavaScript={areaChartJS}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```